# How to set a field from C++ to Java, using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a java class:

```
public class LibClass
{
    public static String receivedValue;
    ...native methods...
}
```

Then in the c++ code, I want to set the value of the String from C++. I don't want to create new objects, I just want to assign a value to the String.

In C++ I have this so far:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_aries_LibClass_singleCallback
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clz, jstring value)
{
    jclass clazz = (env)->FindClass("com/aries/LibClass");

}
```

I'm looking for something like (env)->SetObjectArrayElement but for Strings.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need methods "GetStaticFieldID()" and "SetStaticObjectField()". A Java String is just an object. (I assume you know how to create a Java String from a native string).

See [Accessing Static Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5901) in the JNI documentation.

Edit: sample C (not C++) code (error checking omitted)

```
jstring str;
JNIEnv *env;
jclass clazz;
jfieldID fid;

// initialize str and env here ...

clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "my/package/MyClass");
fid = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, clazz , "myField", "Ljava/lang/String;");
(*env)->SetStaticObjectField(env, clazz, fid, str);
```

Comment: I'm using a jstring but I can't get these 2 methods to work though. Either my signatures are incorrect or I'm not assigning it correctly on the Java side.
Do you have some sample code?

Comment: Optionally, can I have the jni function call a non-native java method?
Like, can JNI call something like "public void receiver(String text)" ?

Comment: I don't have sample code handy, but Google or the like will surely find something if you search for the method names and "example". And I'm not sure I understand your second question. You always call non-native methods via JNI from C code. (The "native" keyword is for the other direction, calling C code from Java code.)

Comment: I've added a sample of the basic steps.

Comment: Dude I feel like I should buy you lunch. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Why does it need the `;` at the end (`"Ljava/lang/String;"`) while other types (e.g., `"J"`) don't?

Comment: `I`, `J` and the like are primitive types specified by a single character in a method signature. `L` tells the method parsing the signature that a class name will follow. This class name needs an end delimiter, which is the `;`. A class name could end with an `I` or another character used for a primitive type and without the delimiter there would be no way to distinguish that

Answer (score 0):

Do you already check http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html ?
P.S. The second argument of *singleCallback* should probably be *jobject* type (this).

Comment: Yeah I've read that site a few times now, but this only refers to methods though. 
I want to assign a public variable directly

Comment: Well, possible workaround is to create static method-setter for such variables and use it.